# Fix edge intersections between upper face and front when drawing a cube axonometrically?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to remove the extra edge (meaning that it "overflows") when I am trying to draw the upper face of a cube. As you can see, it does not perfectly align with the side of the cube:

[image]
[image]

Is there any way I can achieve this, if I want the thickness to remain the same and the base of the parallelogram to be the same length as one side of the square?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Round corner in stroke settings can work better although it isn't geometrically perfect cube either:

[image]

Geometrically perfect cube is complex if there must be thick stroke-like edges. You must decide which part of each thick stroke belongs to which surface and draw them with the right projection.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want rounded corners which is one way to solve the problem, another possible method would be to combine both shapes with the Shape Builder tool, then redraw the horizontal line.

Example

[image]

Comment: The top right corner still needs something. I guess the same trick works 2nd time.

Comment: @user287001 Well, if you were making a full cube, with three pieces, it should still work, but you'd need to redraw the three inside lines. [See example](https://imgur.com/W2i8H27)

Comment: @BillyKerr protip: turn the object manipulator handles off.Thye are only useful in star shapes. As you seem to reject the intersection snap.

Comment: For me this method is best, as it also allows the use of spatial profiling - in which the outer contours representing edges in space have a heavier lineweight, and the inner lines representing planar intersections but not spatial boundaries have a lesser weight. https://imgur.com/a/wecuOHG